# how to change text between input tags and align label checbox and icon on one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                     /* als je selectbox gebruikt doe dan deze:
                     $("#deliveryType").change(function(){
                         $("img[name=deliveryIcon]").attr("src","images/rushdeliveryicon.png");

                       });
*/
                       $('#deliveryType').click(function() {
                           $deliveryType = document.getElementById("deliveryType");
                            if ($(this).is(':checked') == true) {
                                $deliveryType.value="spoed";
                                $('#deliveryType').text("Spoedlevering");
                                $("img[name=deliveryIcon]").attr("src","images/rushdeliveryicon.png");
                            }else{
                                $deliveryType.value="week";
                                $('#deliveryType').text("Weeklevering");
                                $("img[name=deliveryIcon]").attr("src","images/weekdeliveryicon.png");
                            }
                        });
                    });


                </script>


            <label id="deliverylabel" for="delivery">Leveringsoort
                <!--    <select name="deliveryType" id="deliveryType" >
                        <option value="week">Weeklevering</option>
                        <option value="rush">Spoedlevering</option>
                    </select>
                -->
                <input name="deliveryType" id="deliveryType" type="checkbox" value="week" >Weeklevering</input>

            <img name="deliveryIcon" src="images/weekdeliveryicon.png" style="width:64px;height:64px;" /></label>
```

If i click the checkbox then the text between the input tags need to change:

```
 <input name="deliveryType" id="deliveryType" type="checkbox" value="week">Weeklevering</input>
```

Next to this i also try to get the text of the label and the checkbox + text + icon aligned on 1 line so that it fits like the rest of the input fields on the form. Please have a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/nqm4bpnu/

problem with CSS is that the checkbox input also takes this style:

```
div.wrapperDiv
{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

but it because it is a checkbox it doesnt need to have such a big width.

any ideas

thank you

Comment: Good Question. I am giving you an upvote

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to change label for checkbox?

Comment: no the text between <input> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is `<input>` doesn't have a closing tag `(</input>)` so I have changed it to `</input>`, added a `<span>` with different id to display the text and changed `click` to `change` (this doesn't matter but I prefer change event for check box)

**HTML**

```
 <label id="deliverylabel" for="delivery">Leveringsoort</label>
 <input name="deliveryType" id="deliveryType" type="checkbox" value="week" /> 
 <span id="displayTypeText">Weeklevering</span>  <!-- <-----here -->
 <img name="deliveryIcon" src="images/weekdeliveryicon.png" style="width:64px;height:64px;" />
```

**JS**

```
$('#deliveryType').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        this.value = "spoed";
        $('#displayTypeText').text("Spoedlevering");
        $("img[name=deliveryIcon]").attr("src", "images/rushdeliveryicon.png");
    } else {
        this.value = "week";
        $('#displayTypeText').text("Weeklevering");
        $("img[name=deliveryIcon]").attr("src", "images/weekdeliveryicon.png");
    }
});
```

I am not much of a designer but I think you should add a div with `float:left` around this . Anyways here is a working fiddle,

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqm4bpnu/5/)

**UPDATED**

As I have already mentioned I am not a designer but this should get you going  (Add it at the end of the CSS script,

```
 #deliveryType{
    width:30%!important;
 }
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqm4bpnu/6/)

Comment: works, only how do i get the input and lable and icon on 1 line. nicely aligned

Answer (score 1):

Try using this --

1. remove 'Weeklevering' from within your input tag

   `<input name="deliveryType" id="deliveryType" type="checkbox" value="week" >Weeklevering</input>`

and make html like this,

```
<input name="deliveryType" id="deliveryType" type="checkbox" value="week" >
<span id="label">Weeklevering</span>
```

2. change blow line in your jquery code -

   `$('#deliveryType').text("Spoedlevering");`

to this,

```
$('#label').html("Spoedlevering");
```

Note: Do this to both the instances in your jQuery code.

3. To make all three items in single line, add following css -

   `#deliverylabel { display: block; text-align: left; width: 100% !important; }`
   `#deliverylabel > input { display: inline-block; margin-left: 15px; vertical-align: middle; width: auto; }`

hope this helps.

Comment: it works unfortunaly i cant get all on 1 line. see fiddle what happens if i add ur css: http://jsfiddle.net/nqm4bpnu/4/

Comment: Add css code too in your css file as mentioned in #3 in above solution, then it will go in single line

Comment: problem with CSS is that the checkbox input also takes this style:

div.wrapperDiv
{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

Comment: add those css lines at the bottom (in the end) of css then check.